# Uso corretto di "la"

Tags: articles, sentences

Nella seguente frase:

> Ho la tendenza a leggere al buio

Si può omettere il "la"? cosí verrebbe

> Ho tendenza a leggere al buio

Cosí la frase mi suona veramente molto strana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sebbene entrambe le forme siano usate, (vedi [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avere%20tendenza%20a%2Cavere%20la%20tendenza%20a&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavere%20tendenza%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavere%20la%20tendenza%20a%3B%2Cc0)) quella con l'articolo è senz'altro la più comune e quella che suona meglio. Personalmente eviterei la versione senza articolo, ma solo per una questione di gusto personale.

I dizionari mostrano entrambi gli usi, ad esempio:

Tendenza:

> - Disposizione naturale, inclinazione a o per qlco. SIN propensione: ***ha tendenza a ingrassare.***
> - Diffusione di un certo comportamento, ***oggi c'è la tendenza ad assicurarsi***.

[Sabatini Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/T/tendenza.shtml)

Answer (score 4):

Può suonare un po' insolito, ma non c'è motivo per non dire “ho tendenza”.

Ma soprattutto, lo usano scrittori come Natalia Ginzburg (“[ho tendenza a dormire molto](http://tinyurl.com/ybujlo5y)”, “[Io come persona ho tendenza a sentire l'ingiustizia](http://tinyurl.com/ybutcmrc)”), Giovanni Papini (“[ho tendenza a godere della crudeltà](http://tinyurl.com/y8r3l794)”), Primo Levi (“[ho tendenza a farlo quando scrivo](http://www.rigabooks.it/antologie.php?idlanguage=1&id=257&idantologia=397)”), Angelo Morino (“[Ho tendenza a rastrellare fra i residui](http://tinyurl.com/y9htbsxh)”) e [vari altri autori](http://tinyurl.com/yb97h4jc).